# Keycloak social identity API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak, identity

I have react app which use keycloak API for authentication and authorization.

I have social button in my react app when its clicked it should navigate to social identity pages.

I also found a solution which says by passing `kc_idp_hint`.

I tried with this URL

```
const keycloakHost = 'http://localhost:8080';
   const realmName = 'test';
   const clientId = 'account-console';

   // The redirect URL after successful login with LinkedIn
    const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000';

   // Generate the login URL with the kc_idp_hint parameter set to 'linkedin'
   const loginUrl = `${keycloakHost}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?           client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=openid&kc_idp_hint=linkedin`;
```

but the link gives me this error:

> Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Can some please help me with this?

I tried the above method, and I also set the identity providers in keycloak, but gives me invalid redirect URI.